# Cascading parameter from iReport to JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have made a report in *iReport* and while previewing it is prompting for the parameter value

In the *iReport* preview mode it is working file

But while exporting it to the *JasperReports Server* it is not asking for the parameter and showing that "report is empty".

So how to pass the parameter or cascading the parameter in *JasperReports Server* from the *iReport*?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add it manualy. Go to "Repository navigator" (in iReport) find your report, right click Input controls and click on "Create a local input control". The ID must be the same as the name of the parameter.

Jaspersoft studio allows you to create input controls while sending report to server so you don't have to do it manualy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is perfectly working for the single value pass. I am not getting what to do if i want to pass multiple parameters in a dropdown.Means i will select a value from the dropdown and the data will come according to the value from dropdown.Can you please suggest

Comment: When you are creating new input control on "Input control details" tab for "Type" choose `Multi-select list of Values` and click on button `Edit local Resource (List Of Values)` there you can enter values

Comment: not sure how you would do this with a list of values but if you are using a sql source you just need to make sure the $P{} (input #1 ID)  is part of the where clause ( or $X{} if multi select)